# Binding issue after data context changed

Tags: wpf, binding, datacontext

I have a strange problem: I have a WPF screen on which I have an extended `TextBox` that makes some conversions in some cases and that property is bound to a property on view model. When the data context is changed the conversions are reevaluated. When reevaluated my extended `TextBox` has the new data context but the `BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(textBox, dpproperty).DataItem` is still the old data context.
Maybe the conversion that I make is too early after changind the data context? Usually the data context is not changed into the whole screen so the bindings to be reevaluated?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem is, that the bindings of the view do not notice that the `DataContext` is changed. So they are still 'looking' on the VM which was assigned first.

So the best way, to solve the issue is to change the data in the VM assigned as `DataContext` instead of assigning another instance. Since the VM should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` the bindings will update automatically.

Comment: The bindings are refreshed into the whole tree when data context is changed, but in my case i have some bindings on the template of my extended textbox. Here the datacontext is changed with some delay after the control where is used triggers the data context event, so the bindings are refreshed before the datacontext from my exteded textbox template is really changed, so the binding is still pointing to the old datacontext